# $T^n = 0$ but $T^{n-1} \neq 0$: find basis such that $Ta_j = a_{j+1}$ for $j < n$ and $Ta_n = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I solved the first items, but I don't have ideas of how to solve the item (c):

> Suppose $S$ is a linear operator on $n$-dimensional space $V$ such that $S^n=0$ but $S^{n-1}\ne 0$. Prove that there is an ordered basis for $V$ in which the matrix of $A$ consists of $1$s under the main diagonal.

(In other words, a nilpotent linear operator on $n$-dimensional vector space is represented by a matrix with 1 on subdiagonal.)

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: The title of your question really should be more descriptive of the actual math content.  Imagine if all questions on the site were "how to solve this problem?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $S^{n-1} \neq 0$, there is some $v \in V$ such that $S^{n-1}v \neq 0$.

Now consider the ordered list $(v, Sv, \ldots, S^{n-1}v)$. Suppose that some linear combination of these vectors is zero, say $a_0 v + a_1 Sv + \cdots + a_{n-1}S^{n-1}v = 0$.

Apply $S^{n-1}$ to both sides of this equation to obtain $a_0 S^{n-1}v = 0$, so $a_0 = 0$. So $a_1 Sv + \cdots + a_{n-1}S^{n-1}v = 0$.

Apply $S^{n-2}$ to both sides of the new equation  to obtain $a_1 S^{n-1} v = 0$, so $a_1 = 0$.

Continuing in this way, we conclude that $a_0 = a_1 = \cdots = a_{n-1} = 0$. This shows that $(v, Sv, \ldots, S^{n-1}v)$ is a linearly independent list of $n$ vectors, hence a basis for $V$.

Now express $S$ in terms of this basis.